# Does Sorting a List refresh the entire Body View?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to tweak around some SwiftUI code after watching the WWDC keynote + reading some of their tutorials.

However I've bumped to a problem here, and confused with the way View works.

In the code below, I wanted to initially create a button which would sort a List of Cells (similar to that of WWDC), based on alphabetical order.

Hence, I created the sortPlaces() function which would be triggered by tapping the button.

All things good, until:

I also wanted to create a "Featured" Card that would randomly pick 5 out of the available elements in the PlaceStore, then if I tap on the Card, it would change to the next element out of the 5 randomly chosen.

However, when I tried to press the sort button, the List still got in the correct order, but the 5 randomly chosen places got "refreshed" and changed - although I've used different variables that I think would not be interconnected with one another.

My current guess is due to sorting the List, the List View gets refreshed, as well as the entire Body View - thus the getFiveRandomPlaces() function gets re-triggered and the 5 randomly chosen places also changes.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var sortMode = "default"
    @ObjectBinding var store = PlaceStore(places: placedata)
    let storeCopy = PlaceStore(places: placedata)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Featured")
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()

                FeaturedCard(places: getFiveRandomPlaces(places: storeCopy.places))

                ForEach(store.places) { place in
                    PlaceCell(place: place)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Been There"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: sortPlaces) {
                Text("Sort")
            })
            .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }

    func getFiveRandomPlaces(places: [Place]) -> [Place] {
        var placesArrayCopy = places
        var fiveRandomPlaces: [Place] = []
        for _ in 0 ..< 5 {
            let i = Int.random(in: 0 ..< placesArrayCopy.count)
            fiveRandomPlaces.append(placesArrayCopy[i])
            placesArrayCopy.remove(at: i)
        }
        return fiveRandomPlaces
    }

    func sortPlaces() {
        switch sortMode {
        case "default":
            store.places.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
            sortMode = "name"
        case "name":
            store.places.sort { $0.city < $1.city }
            sortMode = "city"
        case "city":
            store.places.sort { $0.country < $1.country }
            sortMode = "country"
        case "country":
            store.places.sort { $0.id < $1.id }
            sortMode = "default"
        default:
            store.places.sort { $0.id < $1.id }
            sortMode = "default"
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the List to still be able to be sorted, but the 5 Randomly Chosen Places/Card stays the same. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance :)

Preview of the App in Simulator: 
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71CRs.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short: yes

I'd say this is expected behaviour. As your view is constantly drawn new when something changes (in your case calling *sortplaces*) you probably should not put business logic inside the view declaration itself.

The decision what your 5 random places are would need to be discerned somewhere else not inside the view.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't totally looking for a solution, an explanation would suffice. Many thanks!